# mustache js - Can't access array value using tables

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I am having a problem with Mustache.js accessing to the values of a json array and I need some help.

The problem is when I want to access to the values using a table. It always shows `[object Object]`, when it should show the array content.

Below is a working and a non-working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/janl/mustache.js/0.7.2/mustache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="template" style="display:none">
  <p>Works but not what I need:</p>
  <p>{{#numbers}} {{.}} {{/numbers}} </p>
  <p>Doesn't work:</p>
  <table>
      <tr>
        {{#numbers}} <th> {{.}} </th> {{/numbers}}
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="rendered"></div>
<script>
var json = {
  "numbers": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  };
var compiledTemplate = Mustache.to_html($('#template').html(), json).replace(/^\s*/mg, '');
$('#rendered').html(compiledTemplate);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output is:

```
Works but not what I need:
1 2 3
Doesn't work:
[object Object]
```

Is there any way to solve this problem or to print the object attributes using mustache.js?

The issue was already asked in their issue system, no replies yet:
https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/295

Thanks,
Mariano.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, this is what I did.

Replaced the div element template, to a script element:

from `<div id="template" style="display:none">` to `<script id="template" type="text/x-mustache-template">`

And worked as expected =)

Comment: you also may have had problems with using mustache against jquery 1.9.1, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650487/icanhaz-mustache-loop-iterate-through-elements-js-error. I had the same problem using icanhaz.js/mustache with jquery 1.9.1. After changing to jquery 1.8.3 the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/janl/mustache.js/0.7.2/mustache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="template" style="display:none">
  <p>Works but not what I need:</p>
  <p>{{#numbers}} {{.}} {{/numbers}} </p>
  <p>Doesn't work:</p>
  <table>
      <tr>
        {{#numbers}} {{{th}}} {{/numbers}}
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="rendered"></div>
<script>
var json = {
  "numbers": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  "th": function () {
    return "<th>" + this + "</th>"
  }
};
var compiledTemplate = Mustache.to_html($('#template').html(), json);
$('#rendered').html(compiledTemplate);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time debugging this.

The problem is `$('#template').html()`. It returns broken HTML because table markup is malformed (stuff outside `<th>` is rendered outside the table by browser)

That is why changing to `<script>` helps